# Filter ADF table using input dates

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I need to be able to filter an ADF table, not using the built-in filtering in an ADF table, but using separate inputDate fields to provide values for the bind variables.  The query works and setting the values from the inputdate fields in the view object (via code) works.  But the table is never rebound because it is still binding to the default values of the bind variables.

I can't find a way to do this.  Please help.

Comment: We need some more info: JDev version, how are you setting your bind variables, how do you execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

I believe is just a refresh problem: you may be missing a partialTrigger between your button triggering search and table. You can check this by pressing F5 - if the problem is just a refresh, you should be seeing the table showing correct data.